# EvalError with angular-elements custom elements in chrome extension manifest version 3

Tags: angular, typescript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, angular14

I am writing a chrome extension that should define different custom elements. I want to use standalone angular components for that. But if I bootstrap them in contentPage.js, I always got an EvalError from Chrome Browser.

[Chrome error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNqnZ.png)

`Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'".`

I thought with aot compiling (which is default in angular 14) JIT compilation should not be a problem anymore. So I don't understand why `angular JitEvaluator` is called here anyway.

package.json

```
{
   "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^14.0.0-beta.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.141",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.32",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "bestzip": "^2.1.7",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "~10.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0"
  }
```

candidate.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './candidate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate.component.scss']
})
export class CandidateComponent implements OnInit {
  public buttonText = '';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  @Input() id = "openButton"
  @Input() class = "";
  @Input() style = "";

  @Input()
    set text(name: string) {
        this.buttonText = name.toUpperCase();
    }

  get name(): string {
        return this.buttonText;
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CandidateComponent } from './components/candidate/candidate.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, CandidateComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  entryComponents: [CandidateComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(CandidateComponent,  {
      injector: this.injector
    });

    customElements.define("app-candidate-button", el);
  }
}
```

contentPage.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from '../../angular/src/app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build with the production flag `ng build --prod`